# Javascript : replace reg exp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace all symbols that aren't letters by `-`, but my code doesn't work :

```
 $reg = '/[^a-zA-Z]+/g';  
 $txt = $txt.replace($reg, '-');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to un-quote the regex string so it's treated as a regular expression literal, so you get this:

```
$reg = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;  
$txt = $txt.replace($reg, '-');
```

Regular expressions in JavaScript don't need to be quoted as strings unless using the `new Regexp()` notation; in the above example, it is now a *regular expression literal*, which isn't treated as a string but a piece of regex to be used in `.replace()`.

Answer (score 4):

Regular Expressions in JavaScript are not strings.

```
reg = /[^a-z]+/gi;
txt = txt.replace(reg, '-');
```

You don't need to place quotes around them.

Comment: My vote goes +1 for using `/i` rather than `[a-zA-Z]` and +17 for removing the `$` on the variables.

Comment: Might be nice to have some `var` in there, though :p

Comment: @Phrogz it's inferred from the OP's question that the variables were already declared (as he isn't using var in his examples). Though yes, that would be nice to have on top of the code/function/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

do not use quote on regex. Without quotes, they are **RegEx** object. With quotes they are just string.

Use,

```
$reg = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around your regex.

If it is your intention for multiple non-alpha characters in a row to be replaced with a single hyphen your regex will then work. If you want multiple non-alpha characters to be replaced with multiple hyphens then you should also remove the `+` sign.